# Sorting a CSV file alphabetically and also with the greatest number

Tags: sorting, csv, python-3.x

I currently have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
Name    Class   Score 1 Score 2 Score 3
Hussain 1       0       0       3
Bon     2       1       2       3
Alice   1       5       2       3
Josh    3       1       7       10
Jack    2       0       8       9
Zyra    3       5       1       6
```

I want to be able to sort this file so that when the user chooses either class 1, class 2 or class 3, the program will find every student in that particular class and sort their names alphabetically. I finally need to be able to retrieve each student's highest score out of all scores. I have been trying to figure this out countless times and seem to be getting nowhere. What I wish the result of this to be is: The results can contain colons if needed, shown in examples.

If the user chooses CLASS1:

```
Alice:5 or Alice 5
Hussain:3 or Hussain 3
```

If the user chooses CLASS2:

```
Bob:3 or Bob 3
Jack:9 or Jack 9
```

And finally if the user chooses CLASS3:

```
Josh:10 or Josh 10
Zyra:6 or Zyra 6
```

I really appreciate any help as I have been struggling with this for a very long time. Thank you.

Comment: That is not really a proper csv because of the ambiguous fields.

Comment: By ambiguous fields do you mean the "Score 1", "Score 2" and "Score 3" fields? Even so, is it not possible for me to solve this problem - and how so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you fix the headers so that you can interpret that data as a space delimited:

```
txt='''\
Name    Class   Score_1 Score_2 Score_3
Hussain 1       0       0       3
Bob     2       1       2       3
Alice   1       5       2       3
Josh    3       1       7       10
Jack    2       0       8       9
Zyra    3       5       1       6'''
```

In Python 3 you can create a dict of lists of the data like so:

```
from io import StringIO

with StringIO(txt) as f:
    header=next(f).split()
    data={e:[] for e in header}
    for line in f:
        li=line.split()
        li=[li[0]]+list(map(int, li[1:]))
        for k, e in zip(header, li):
            data[k].append(e)
```

Now you have:

```
>>> {'Score_1': [0, 1, 5, 1, 0, 5], 'Name': ['Hussain', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Josh', 'Jack', 'Zyra'], 'Score_2': [0, 2, 2, 7, 8, 1], 'Class': [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3], 'Score_3': [3, 3, 3, 10, 9, 6]}
```

Then a simple list comprehension gets what you want:

```
for tgt_cls in (1,2,3): 
    li=['{}:{}'.format(data['Name'][i], 
                 max(data['Score_'+s][i] for s in '123')) for i, cls in enumerate(data['Class']) if cls==tgt_cls]
    print(tgt_cls, sorted(li))
```

Prints:

```
1 ['Alice:5', 'Hussain:3']
2 ['Bob:3', 'Jack:9']
3 ['Josh:10', 'Zyra:6']
```

Comment: I have been working with the code and appreciate your help, however I have come across an issue which states  KeyError:"Class" . I do not understand the cause of this error and have been stumped on this problem for hours now. The actual error refers to the line where enumerate is being used. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is in the `headers` list? Replace what would have been the header element for `'Class'`